# Undefined al llamar función mediante ajax

Tags: jquery, ajax, json, asp.net-core

Tengo el siguiente script el cual mediante el onchange me captura el valor de un dropdownlist que se almacenara en la variable `selectval`, posterior a esto haciendo uso de `Ajax` envió el dato capturado a mi método `Get_Pieza_Lista` que me debería devolver el resultado como se ve en la imagen de debug con un total de 34 resultados, pero al momento de visualizar en la pagina a traves de la consola me visualiza `undefined` como se ve en la imagen, en teoría al enviar los datos por ajax estaría correcto que vaya entre "" o deberian ir entre '', en la variable data debe ir el nombre de la columna a la que evaluare y que se muestra en la imagen como resultado, que problema causa que me devuelva ese `undefined`?

```
 <script>
    $('#MODEL_PRESUPUESTO_PRE_DEN_PAC').change( function () {

        var selectedVal = document.getElementById("MODEL_PRESUPUESTO_PRE_DEN_PAC").value;
        if (selectedVal == "DENTADURA TEMPORAL") {
            selectedVal = "TEMPORAL"
        }
        else if (selectedVal == "DENTADURA ADULTA") {
            selectedVal = "ADULTA"
        }
        alert(selectedVal);
        $.ajax(
            {
                type: "POST",
                dataType: "json",
                url: "/Presupuesto/Get_Pieza_Lista",
                data: { 'PIE_DENT': selectedVal },
                success:
                    function (resul) {
                          // VACIAMOS EL DropDownList
                        $("#MODEL_PRESUPUESTO_PRE_PIE_DEN").empty();
                        //AÑADIMOS UN NUEVO label CON EL NOMBRE DEL ELEMENTO SELECCIONADO
                        $("#MODEL_PRESUPUESTO_PRE_PIE_DEN").append("<option value> -- ESCOGA UNA PIEZA DENTAL " + $("#MODEL_PRESUPUESTO.PRE_PIE_DEN option:selected").text() + " --</option>")
                        // CONSTRUIMOS EL DropDownList A PARTIR DEL RESULTADO Json(data)
                        $.each(resul, function (index, row) {
                            $("#MODEL_PRESUPUESTO_PRE_PIE_DEN").append("<option value='" + row.PIE_ID + "'>" + row.PIE_PIEZA + "</option>")
                        console.log(resul);
                        });
                      
                    }, error:
                    function (e) {
                        alert("ERROR: " + e.message);
                    }
            });
    })
</script>
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Este es la función que devuelve el resultado visualizado en la imagen pero al momento de enviar el dato a mi formulario me arroja `undefined` pero sin embargo al consultar la variable `resul` como se ve en la imagen sale el resultado , ahora para que no salga este error al cargar en el combo que debería colocar?

```
 [HttpPost]
    public JsonResult Get_Pieza_Lista(String PIE_DENT)
    {
        PIE_DENT = "ADULTA";
        Console.WriteLine("RESUL-->" + PIE_DENT);
        var piezalista = _Context.TBL_PIEZA.Where(x => x.PIE_DENT.Equals(PIE_DENT)).OrderBy(x => x.PIE_ID).ToList();
        return Json(piezalista);
    }
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: ¿Dónde exactamente ocurre el `undefined`? Cambia esto: `console.log(resul.data);` por esto: `console.log(resul);`  y dinos qué ocurre.

Comment: Si efectivamente, estaba arrojando error al poner .`data`, me podrías explicar el porque el motivo del error? en que difiere de colocar el `data`

Comment: Es muy sencillo, si `resul` **no tiene una propiedad llamada `data`** no puedes hacer esto: `resul.data`.  Cuando tú escribes `resul.data` lo que indicas es: *traeme lo que hay en la propiedad llamada `data` de este objeto* y si el objeto no tiene esa propiedad tendrás derecho a un `undefined`.

Comment: Por ultimo me podrías ayudar nuevamente, edite la pregunte ya que al pasar la informacion para que se cargue en el dropdown me arroja `undefined` :(

Comment: Observa tu salida por consola. **Los nombres de propiedad son *case sensitive* (sensibles a mayúscula/minúscula)**, por tanto, esto es incorrecto: `row.PIE_ID`, esa propiedad se llama `piE_ID` según la imagen, o sea, la `p` y la `i` en minúscula. ¿Me explico? Debes escribir cada propiedad respetando las mayúsculas/minúsculas. Si tú escribes `row.piE_ID` sí encontrará el dato. Y si intentas obtener más propiedades lo mismo, debes respetar las mayúsculas/minúsculas. Cometes **el mismo error** también aquí: `row.PIE_PIEZA`, debes cambiarlo por `row.piE_PIEZA`

Comment: Y, cuando el código te funcione, evita usar `append` dentro de bucles, es una pésima práctica.

Comment: Cuando te refieres a case sensitive es algo que debo controlar mediante codigo o es propio de `ajax`?, porque se da este tipo de situación si al momento de hacer el query en mi método `Get_Pieza_Lista` están con mayúscula las columnas de la bd , como puedo corregir esto o es propio de `ajax` o de `Jquery`, y disculpa tanta molestia.

Comment: No es algo propio de Ajax, eso debe ser más bien algo que ocurre en tu backend. Yo no reconozco el código que hay al final de tu pregunta por lo que no podría decirte más. Lo que ocurre aquí posiblemente es que el backend haga esas conversiones  de los nombres de propiedad por algún motivo. No sé si eso tenga que ver con ASP ¿? Realmente no tengo ni idea de esa plataforma.

Comment: Simplemente Ajax está recibiendo el objeto así, y tú debes leer el objeto en Ajax escribiendo las propiedades como Ajax las recibe. Si quieres que Ajax reciba los nombres de propiedades en mayúscula tendrás que ver en tu backed cómo lograr eso. Ese es ya otro asunto que no tiene nada que ver con el problema inicial...

Comment: Y por ultimo para no molestar, para evitar el uso de `append` que debería usar?

Comment: Te escribí una respuesta indicando los tres problemas respectivos a tu pregunta. Y no es ninguna molestia, si se presentan situaciones nuevas u otros asuntos sobre este código u otro puedes plantearlo en nuevas preguntas. Todo esto enriquece el contenido del sitio y servirá como referencia a más usuarios con problemas parecidos.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Lo que tienes en `resul` sería la respuesta del servidor. Y, dado que ese objeto no tiene ninguna propiedad `data` no puedes hacer esto: `resul.data`, pues tendrás derecho a un `undefined`.

Por otra parte, las propiedades de objeto son *case sensitive* (sensibles a mayúscula/minúscula). En la imagen se ve que Ajax está recibiendo el objeto con propiedades como `piE_ID`, `piE_PIEZA` etc por tanto debes respetar eso cuando intentes obtener los datos en `row`.

Por último, no uses nunca `append` dentro de bucles, es una pésima práctica, porque `append()` modificaría el DOM en cada iteracción del bucle y esto tiene su coste (cuando el DOM es modificado ocurre una nueva renderización), por eso es mejor concatenar todo en una variable y hacer un solo `append()` al salir del bucle. Así ocurrirá una sola renderización, no `N` renderizaciones, según la cantidad de elementos que haya en el bucle.

Aplicando lo dicho, la parte del `success` quedaría así:

```
            success:
                function (resul) {
                      // VACIAMOS EL DropDownList
                    $("#MODEL_PRESUPUESTO_PRE_PIE_DEN").empty();
                    var mOptions=`<option value="">-- ESCOGA UNA PIEZA DENTAL ${$("#MODEL_PRESUPUESTO.PRE_PIE_DEN option:selected").text()}--</option>`;
                    // CONSTRUIMOS EL DropDownList A PARTIR DEL RESULTADO Json(data)
                    $.each(resul, function (index, row) {
                        mOptions+=`<option value="${row.piE_ID}">${row.piE_PIEZA}</option>`;
                    });
                    $("#MODEL_PRESUPUESTO_PRE_PIE_DEN").append(mOptions);                     
                }, error:
```

Comment: Gracias campeón!, un abrazo por toda la ayuda brindada!

Comment: @Carrobe90 se me escapó esto: `$("#MODEL_PRESUPUESTO_PRE_PIE_DEN").append("<option value> -- ESCOGA UNA PIEZA DENTAL " + $("#MODEL_PRESUPUESTO.PRE_PIE_DEN option:selected").text() + " --</option>")`, conviene ponerlo también en `mOptions`, ahora edito para arreglar ese pequeño despieste.